# select element on currentTarget

Tags: javascript

I know this is pretty easy but I can not figure it out!

```
<ul class="footer_nav">
    <span class='footer_header'>01</span>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="footer_nav">
    <span class='footer_header'>01</span>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have the above HTML. What I would like to do is when a hover event is happening on `li.a` I change the CSS value of .span but only in the currentTarget.

I am using

```
e.currentTarget
```

But using this how do you select another element within the current `UL` that can be updated but only in the current `UL` not all spans

```
Here is my current coffeescript...

  $('ul.footer_nav').hover (e) ->
    changeFooterHover(e)


##functions
  changeFooterHover = (e) ->
    span = e.currentTarget.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')
    span.toggleClass("selected");
```

with the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'toggleClass'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when a hover event is happening on li.a I change the CSS value of .span but only in the currentTarget". If you want to get a different element within the `ul`, then you can use `e.currentTarget.parentNode` to get the `ul` element, then use things like `getElementsByTagName` or whatever. It depends on what you want and what you already are doing. Post some Javascript code!

Comment: appologies I have added some code, please can you undown vote my post

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery then you can do it like the following:

```
$("ul li a").mouseenter(function(e){
    var anchorElt = $(this);
    anchorElt.parent().parent().find("span").text(anchorElt.text());
});
```

This is ofcourse if you have multiple ul elements in your html if not then you can just find the span from your ul element and change the value.

Answer (score 0):

you could just find the span:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('footer_header')[0];
```

...or with jQuery:

```
var elem = $(this).closest('ul').find('.footer_header');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need this:

This will help you to stop bubbling event on outer elements.

**http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/**

Answer (score -1):

You can use *.closest()* function to get to the UL element you want.

```
    $( 'li a' ).hover( function() {
        $( this ).closest( 'ul' ).find( 'span' ).html( 'over' );
    },
    function() {
        $( this ).closest( 'ul' ).find( 'span' ).html( 'out' );
    });
```

Something like above might help you get on the right track.

Comment: Why the downvote? You **can** use _.closest()_ function and do what was asked at the begining.